# In 2013 did an SPD delegate conference vote on a proposed "grand coalition" in Germany, and if so what proportions of delegates voted for and against?

Tags: germany

In 2018, the leadership of the Social Democratic Party (SPD) has proposed a coalition government with the Christian Democratic Party (CDU) and Christian Social Union (CSU), known as a "grand coalition" ("Groko"). First a vote was taken among about 700 delegates at a conference, which "try to achieve a  Groko" won by 56% to 44%, and now a vote has started among the party's 470,000 members (on "go ahead and implement the provisional agreement with the other parties")

In 2013, the SPD leadership proposed a similar grand coalition with the CDU and CSU, and in a vote among the membership 76% voted in favour. In that year, prior to the members' vote was there also a vote at a delegate conference? If so, what proportions of delegates voted for and against Groko?

For those who like graphics:

[image]

Comment: The question is a bit misleading, as are the numbers. The party conventions decided about whether to start negotiations; it was not known at that point what the future coalition agreement might look like. The membership polls, on the other hand, were/are about accepting a concrete proposal.

Comment: Thanks for this. The difference between a NoGroko vote at the delegates' conference and a NoGroko vote in the members' ballot was between "we don't want a Groko" and "we don't want the Groko you propose". You might have suggested a concrete improvement. I've now amended question and answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, an SPD convention of "nearly 230 delegates" considered the Groko proposal on 20 October 2013. **Around 85% voted in favour** of attempting to agree a Groko. ([Source](http://www.dw.com/en/spd-on-its-way-to-a-grand-coalition/a-17170856).)